# Awk shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i have a file .dat with this format

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
933|Mahinda|Perera|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
1129|Carmen|Lepland|female|1984-02-18|2010-02-28T04:39:58.781+0000|81.25.252.111|Internet Explorer
```

and i want to replace a column (number of column is given from user with the command `./tool.sh -f <file> --edit <id> <column> <value>`) with the value (value is given from user with the same command) i cannot insert `<column>` parameter inside awk

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1"="-f" ] ; then
   if [ "$3"="--edit" ] ; then

y=$6 
x="$"$5
awk -F '|' ' '$4'==$1{$x-=$y;print }'  <$2

fi
fi
```

i want something like this when user give this command

```
./file.sh -f file --edit 933 3 spyros
```

(the 3rd field than before has the value "Perera" change to "spyros)

```
933|Mahinda|spyros|male|1989-12-03|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Firefox
```

Comment: It's very unclear what your awk script is supposed to do. You seem to be mixing up shell syntax with awk syntax and awk fields with shell positional parameters and/or variables. And idk why you have a `-=` in there at all given your description. Edit your question to provide a better explanation, an example of the operation you want to perform, and the expecte output given your posted sample input.

Comment: You should probably show us a sample invocation of your script.  For example, you discuss `./tool.sh -f --edit`, but that makes `--edit` into `$2`, yet you test for it in `$3`.  It looks as if you redirect from `$2`, so presumably you mean `./tool.sh -f filename --edit …`, but it isn't wholly clear what you expect in arguments 4, 5 and 6.  You should probably use `-v` to convey values to `awk` from the shell.

Comment: i edit my question with the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want this:

```
awk -v key="$4" -v fldNr="$5" -v val="$6" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1==key{$fldNr=val;print}' "$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ed-morton, but I've used named fields:

```
awk -v id=933 -v field=lastName -v value=spyros \
'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"} NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]=i; print} NR>1 {if($a["#id"]==id) $a[field]=value; print}' \
file
```